# Pairwise comparison after repeated measures ANOVA interpretation

Tags: r, statistics, anova, posthoc

I ran a one way ANOVA with repeated measures:

```
aov <- aov(score ~ group*time + Error(subject/time), data=valueAest)
```

However, the result is hard to interpret as to whether the group difference comes from before treatment, after treatment, or both?

```
Error: subject
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
group      1  12.01  12.013   4.424 0.0421 *
Residuals 38 103.17   2.715                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subject:time
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
time        1  0.012  0.0125   0.029  0.866
group:time  1  0.013  0.0125   0.029  0.866
Residuals  38 16.475  0.4336
```

so I decided to run some post-hoc analysis. Looking at some answers from other people, I used the multcomp library:

```
lme_score = lme(score ~ group, data=valueAest, random = ~1|subject)
anova(lme_score)

require(multcomp)
summary(glht(lme_score, linfct=mcp(group = "Tukey")), test = adjusted(type = "bonferroni"))
```

but this gave me error of ‘ncol(linfct)’ is not equal to ‘length(coef(model))’.

I also tried:

```
Mixed_Fitted_Interaction<-emmeans(aov, ~group|time)
Mixed_Fitted_Interaction

# pairwise comparison 
pairs(Mixed_Fitted_Interaction)
```

This gave me the following result:

```
time = recreation1:
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 map - VR    -0.75 0.397 49.8 -1.890  0.0646 

time = recreation2:
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 map - VR    -0.80 0.397 49.8 -2.016  0.0492
```

This looks promising in my naive mind, can I draw the conclusion that the significance actually doesn't come from treatment, but from the population difference?

Comment: Not sure why the difference would come from treatment, given that neither the treatment (`time`) main effect, nor the interaction are significant. The main effect of group is essentially collapsed across time, so the difference lies between one of your group comparisons

Comment: the treatment is group not time. I essentially want to find the difference between "group" but looks like the group difference exist before treatment

Comment: @April If `group` is your treatment shouldn't the model be `aov(score ~ group*time + Error(subject/group), data=valueAest)`? In the model you give, `time` is the main (treatment) effect.

Comment: [continued] It would help if you were to clarify on your experiment design. What are your between-group and within-group variables. Are they fully crossed?